# What does location actually mean in the Altium part providers preferences?

Tags: altium

Please see the option inside the red box:

[image]

I am unable to find what exactly is meant by "Location" for a part. Is this:

1. Location of manufacture
2. Location where it is stocked
3. Create by an organisation that is head office in that country
4. Something else ... ?
5. And why is this relevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Defining Part Provider Preferences for Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/data-management-parts-providers-preferences)

According to Altium, "Part Provider" describes suppliers such as Mouser, Digi-Key, etc... So the location seems to describe the country in which the provider is located. I don't think it has anything to do with where the component is manufactured, since this can vary even for a single part.

If you are located in country X you may want to only buy from suppliers located in country X, since the shipping costs and lead times may be longer for suppliers in other countries...